# MYSQL: Sum of other column from a Distinct column

Tags: mysql

I have a single table like this:

```
from_date   |   fare
2016-09-23  |   10.35
2016-09-23  |   7.50
2016-09-24  |   20.05
2016-09-25  |   9.45
```

and I want return the distinct sum of the fare.
the returned results should be like this:

```
from_date   |   fare
2016-09-23  |   17.85
2016-09-24  |   20.05
2016-09-25  |   9.45
```

i tried using this query

```
SELECT SUM(FARE) as FARE FROM (SELECT DISTINCT from_date_time as datefrom, fare as FARE) t
```

but it doesn't return the way i want it.
how should i build my query?

Comment: `select sum(fare) as fare,from_date from table_name group by from_date`

Comment: Distinct SUM? Did you mean DISTINCT date?

Answer (score 1):

First, you never want a sum of distinct values.  If you find that you need that, something is seriously wrong with your data model

Second, your sample data suggest that you just want a sum:

```
select from_date, sum(fare)
from singletable t
group by from_date;
```

Answer (score 0):

you just need to group data by date (by the field u need to be distinct)

```
SELECT from_date, SUM(fare) as fare FROM table_t GROUP BY from_date
```